# Adding two or more list based on it's pair in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, list-manipulation

I am not too proficient with functional style and I don't want to use any **set** functions, so I have a problem. I am really struggling whether I should do recursively or in a different manner.

I have a collection of pairs in a list, like so:

```
((4 2) (3 1) (3 2) (2 4) etc...)
```

In this pair '(4 2), the second element '2' tells me which other pairs it **matches** to, in this case '(3 2).
So, I add these two pairs together using their first element, in this case, it's '4' and '3'.
The new pair is now '(7 2). And so on for **other pairs in the list** too.
Finally, it should return:

```
 ((7 2) (3 1) (2 4))
```

I would care less about the order.
.
I already have a working function that add two different pairs. The only assumption with this function is that the pairs are matching.

Consequently, what I want to do is manipulated this list of pairs to return a list in these manners.

Examples:

```
 take the list ((4 2) (3 1) (3 2) (2 4))    
 matching-pairs: '(4 2) and '(3 2)

 and then return --> ((7 2) (3 1) (2 4))


 take the list ((2 1) (3 2) (1 2) (5 1) (6 3))
 matching-pairs: '(2 1) and '(5 1)
                 '(3 2) and '(1 2)

 and then return --> ((7 1) (4 2) (6 3))
```

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over your list and store each pair's `car` into a list in an `assoc` that looks like this:

```
original: ((2 . 1) (3 . 2) (1 . 2) (5 . 1) (6 . 3))
new:      ((1 . (2 5))
           (2 . (3 1))
           (3 . (6))
```

Then sum together all the `cdr`s and flip each pair to get this:

```
          ((7 . 1) (4 . 2) (6 . 3))
```

Comment: That looks a very good way to do it. Could you give a brief idea too, for making the new list in an 'assoc' as you said ? I am new to functional style and my mind keeps switching to procedural style.

Comment: The details of association lists can be found [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node153.html). Basically, you want to first go through the source list and create the alist from it (hint: use `map`). You may want to add the items up as you go, or you may want to put them all in a list, as nooodl suggested. Then, you can add them up if you didn't do that earlier, and flip the data back into whatever structure you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun get-pairs (alist index)
  (cond
   (alist
    (if (= (nth 1 (car alist)) index)
       (append (list (caar alist)) (get-pairs (cdr alist) index))
       (get-pairs (cdr alist) index)))
  ((not alist)
   'nil)))


(defun get-iterator (alist)
  (labels
    ((f (alist res)
        (cond
          (alist
            (if (member (nth 1 (car alist)) res)
              (f (cdr alist) res)
              (f (cdr alist) (append (cdar alist) res))))
          ((not alist)
            res))))
    (f alist 'nil)))


(defun get-value (alist)
  (loop for i in (get-iterator alist)
        collect (get-pairs alist i)))

(defun list-sum (alist)
  (loop for i in (get-value alist)
        collect (apply #'+ i)))

(defun match-value (alist)
  (loop for i in (get-iterator alist)
        for j in (list-sum alist)
        collect (append (list j) (list i))))


(defparameter *my-list* '((2 1) (3 1) (4 2) (5 2) (8 1) (9 2) (1 3) (0 3)))

(print (match-value *my-list*))
```

Sorry for the messy code but that should do the trick if I understood the problem right.